# Angular router: ignore slashes in path parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, url, routes, angular-router

I have dynamic routes that **could** contain slashes or anti-slashes inside parameters , for example:

`http://localhost:4200/dashboard/T64/27D` I should navigate to a page with route `T64/27D`

Here's how I navigate
`this.router.navigate(['dashboard/'+this.groupListPage[0].code]);`
`this.groupList[0].code` contain `T64/27D`

Actually Angular separate `T64` and `27D` as 2 different pages.

Here's the error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard/T64/27D'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard/T64/27D'
```

How can I tell to Angular that `/` is a part of the param ?

Comment: What you can do is to get the 2 parts of the parameter in different variables, something like `dashboard/:param1/:param2'` in your state, and recompose it afterwards using `param1 + '/' + param2`. A workaround in a way, but it should work

Comment: The problem is that not always I have a slash ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do this with pathparams. It would perfectly work with queryparams tho.

You can also try to escape the slash with %2F, but I am not 100% sure how angular will take/parse this.

Comment: That's solved the issue, Angular parse well the param and transform automatically  %2F to /

Answer (score 11):

Assumming the route:

```
{
    path: 'dashboard/:id',
    component: FooComponent
 }
```

And :id can exist in {'abc','ab/c'}, in order to consider the inner '/' as part of the path, you need to use a custom [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher):

```
const customMatcher: UrlMatcher = (
  segments: UrlSegment[],
  group: UrlSegmentGroup,
  route: Route
): UrlMatchResult => {
  const { length } = segments;
  const firstSegment = segments[0];
  if (firstSegment.path === "dashboard" && length === 2 || length === 3) {
    // candidate for match
    const idSegments = segments
      .slice(1); // skip prefix
    const idPaths = idSegments.map(segment => segment.path);
    const mergedId = idPaths.join('/');// merge the splitted Id back together
    const idSegment: UrlSegment = new UrlSegment(mergedId, { id: mergedId });
    return ({ consumed: segments, posParams: { id: idSegment } });
  }
  return null;
};
```

A working example can be found in this [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ignore-slash?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: I have discovered the UrlMatcher thanks to you, Nawsen response solved the issue and in my case it's simpler than UrlMatcher

Comment: It was hard to find really useful example how to map a parameter with slashes.Thank you a lot.

Comment: LOVE IT! Just 2 heads up for use: the customMatcher is hardcoded, modify 1) the path  === "dashboard" to your application, and also 2) the parameter name in return(… { id:      - I had used     path/:tool instead of path/:id so had to rename to tool: idSegment

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still looking for this, if you have special characters in your `param` you use `navigate` method in following way:

```
this.router.navigate(['dashboard', param]);
```

This way Angular will automatically escape special characters in `param`

Answer (score -2):

```
  You must define it in your routes.
  //if two param
  {
    path: 'dashboard/:id1/:id2',
    component: yourComponent
  }
  //if only one param
 {
     path: 'dashboard/:id1',
     component: yourComponent
 }
 {
     path: 'dashboard',
     component: yourComponent
 }
 and then navigate to your path
 this.router.navigate(['dashboard/'+this.groupListPage[0].code]);
```

Comment: A possible solution, but a poor one. Handling the recomposition of the id parameter in the same component is extra logic that you havent included.

Comment: the question was to identify the route path. So i gave the appropriate answer. The use Of ActivatedRoute to get the parameter value is extra logic, but i haven't included it since its not relevant to the question.