# How to consume Angulars routing UrlMatchResult from UrlMatcher in the component?

Tags: angular, routes

Im struggling with routing in Angular 10. To my URL I want to add a token that contains several time (various quantities) `/` char. To avoid Angular routing get lost, [basing on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50408905/12603542), I decided to use `UrlMatcher`. Everything seem to be ok, but at the end I have no idea how to consume returned parameters from the matcher.

Router:

```
const customMatcher: UrlMatcher = (segments: UrlSegment[]): UrlMatchResult => {
  const { length } = segments;
  console.log('segments qty: ' + length);
  for (var i = 2; i < length; i++) {
    console.log(segments[i].path);
  }
  if (segments.length > 0) {
    const firstSegment = segments[0];
    if (firstSegment.path === "pass-reset") {
      const slicedSegments = segments.slice(2);
      const idPaths = slicedSegments.map(segment => segment.path);
      const mergedToken = idPaths.join('/');// merge the splitted Id back together
      const tokenSegment: UrlSegment = new UrlSegment(mergedToken, { token: mergedToken });
      return ({ consumed: segments, posParams: { email: segments[1], token: tokenSegment } });
    }
  }
  return null;
};

const routes: Routes = [
  { matcher: customMatcher, component: PassResetComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Component:

```
(...)
email: Observable<string>;
token: Observable<string>;
(...)
getPassResetModel(): PassResetModel {
    this.email = this.route.paramMap.pipe(map(params => params.get('email')));
    this.token = this.route.paramMap.pipe(map(params => params.get('token')));
    console.log('email: ' + this.email);
    console.log('token: ' + this.token);

    var model = <PassResetModel>{};
    model.Email = this.email;
    model.Password = '';
    model.Token = this.token;

    return model;
(...)
```

In my component there is a problem. When debuging (in browsers console) I receive:

```
email: [object Object]
token: [object Object]
```

I have no idea how to convert the result. Documentation does not say too much about [UrlMatchResult](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatchResult) and [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher). Also not many examples are in the SO.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues with your implementation:

1. `UrlMatchResult` `PosParams` are not `any` type, they are a map of strings to `UrlSegment`.

https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatchResult

The issue you are seeing is due to the type that you are returning from you `CustomMatcher`. It is not a valid `UrlMatchResult`

An example of a valid return type would be:

```
return {
  consumed: segments,
  posParams: {
    email: new UrlSegment(segments[i], {}),
    token: new UrlSegment(tokenSegment, {})
  }
}
```

You are correct that the documentation on this is not very good. It is not clear to me why it uses UrlSegment type

2. `ParamMap` is an Observable. `this.route.paramMap.pipe(...)` returns an Observable. To get access to the values inside that observable you can either subscribe to that Observable or change your call to `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get(...)`. The **snapshot** field returns an `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` instead of an `ActivatedRoute`, which contains values instead of Observables.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to apply for this problem by using JSON copy api.

as you can see:

```
email: console.log('email: ' + JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.email)));
```

Comment: `you can try to apply for this problem by using JSON copy api.` What is for you exactly the "copy api" from JSON ? And this does not answer the question.